# Value casting issue: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'cards_basic.Card'

Tags: ios, swift

**UPDATE2**

My desired behaviour would be to pass a Card from the tableview to the detail view. I have done it several times when JSON/Alamofire was not involved, but now when the array containing the Cards is displayed on the tableview and then I try to perform a segue to the detailed view passing the tapped Card, I get the error describe here.

**UPDATE**

```
var cards = [Card]()
var cardToPass: Card!
```

I am retrieving a JSON array from an api endpoint, displaying that in a TableView, then trying to navigate to the detail view, like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate

    let data = [...] // real data here in the code

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, API["PROTOCOL"]! + API["HOST"]! + API["URL"]!, parameters: data)
        .responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in
            self.cards = JSON as! [AnyObject]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toSharedDetailCard") {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SharedDetailController
        viewController.passedCard = cardToPass
    }
}
```

I am getting this error `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x105672a60) to 'cards_basic.Card' (0x104ccf970).` for this line `viewController.passedCard = cardToPass` and I don’t really know how to fix it.

Comment: What is `cardToPass `?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: The exception is pretty clear- `cardToPass` is an instance of `NSDictionary` and you are trying to assign it to a property of type `Card` - this won't work.  How did you create/define `cardToPass`?

Comment: I added the declaration of cardToPass. In the target viewController, passedCard is also defined like that.